# Changing Facebook Post Date with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can post on my wall with Graph API.

```
$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);
```

Then, I can change their date manually. Is it possible to change the date of a post or create a new post with a past date through Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Graph API doc - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ under the Publishing section, it shows the available arguments that cane be used when posting to a wall and they are message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source, place, tags.
But if you are using OG actions, you will be able to publish posts referencing past activities. More info here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/publish-past-actions/

Comment: Hey deesarus , I try a lot to post on previous date, can you please an example